# Is there an ideal flag for questions in the "avoid asking" category of Biology.SE?

Tags: discussion, flagging

It seems like there are many posts that are eventually flagged for removal because they are not the right type of questions for the site, as described [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

The only flag I see that can apply to these is to label them as "blatantly off topic" unless they fall under some of the other off-topic categories (homework, etc) - unfortunately, that flag doesn't seem appropriate to all cases, and there are sometimes questions which could be rescued albeit with substantial effort (that is, they do not "have nothing to do with biology" but they might be discussion questions, or could work with modification on another SE site).

Am I missing a flag that others in the community commonly use in these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that the question may be suitable for some other SE site, then leave a comment and raise a moderator-attention flag suggesting a migration to the relevant site.

Questions closed for reasons such as "too broad", "primarily opinion-based" or "unclear what you are asking" cannot be rescued unless they are suitably edited. When a relevant edit has been made, you can cast a reopen vote. If you do not have sufficient reputation then you can raise the issue in chat or meta. Please **do not** flag these cases for moderator attention. These matters should be dealt by the community and not by the moderators alone. Moreover, a moderator may not be familiar with the topic and can therefore not discern whether the question is really on-topic. Same goes for "homeworks".